# How to catch The remote server returned an error: NotFound?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, exception, try-catch, webclient

I work on a project target Windows Phone 7.5 and above.

I use a method to get online image and check the type of the image, if it is gif then I will coonvert it into jpg and bind it to a image control, if jpg and png, just bind with no encoding.

**But codes below throws a error very frequently, "The remote server returned an error: NotFound",why? I have already catch the WebException.**

```
public void GetOnlineImageAndReturnJPGStream(Action<Stream, string> callback, string uriString)
        {
            string errorstring = "";
            try
            {
                WebClient wc = new WebClient();
                wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Referer] = "http://www.xici.net";
                wc.AllowReadStreamBuffering = true;
                wc.OpenReadCompleted += (s, e) =>
                {
                    if (e.Error == null && !e.Cancelled)
                    {
                        //check pic type
                        ImageTypeCheck.ImageType incomingIMGType = ImageTypeCheck.getImageType(e.Result);

                        switch (incomingIMGType)
                        {
                            case ImageTypeCheck.ImageType.Gif://if gif 
                                //deal with gif
                            case ImageTypeCheck.ImageType.Null:
                            case ImageTypeCheck.ImageType.Bmp:
                                //deal with bmp
                            case ImageTypeCheck.ImageType.Jpg:
                            case ImageTypeCheck.ImageType.Png:
                                //deal with jpg and png
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        errorstring = e.Error.Message;
                        callback(e.Result, errorstring);
                    }
                };

                wc.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(uriString, UriKind.Absolute));
            }
            catch (WebException webEx)
            {
                App.ShowToastNotification(webEx.Message);
            }
        }
```

**The unhandle exception is below:**

> {System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error:
>   NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an
>   error: NotFound.    at
>   System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c_*DisplayClasse.b*_d(Object
>   sendState)    at
>   System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c_*DisplayClass1.b*_0(Object
>   sendState)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary()
>   at System.Net.OpenReadCompletedEventArgs.get_Result()    at
>   xicihutong.DataServiceAgent.ServiceAgent.<>c_*DisplayClassa.b*_8(Object
>   s, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)    at
>   System.Net.WebClient.OnOpenReadCompleted(OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
>   at System.Net.WebClient.OpenReadOperationCompleted(Object arg)}
>       [System.Net.WebException]: {System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The
>   remote server returned an error: NotFound.    at
>   System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c_*DisplayClasse.b*_d(Object
>   sendState)    at
>   System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c_*DisplayClass1.b*_0(Object
>   sendState)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary()
>   at System.Net.OpenReadCompletedEventArgs.get_Result()    at
>   xicihutong.DataServiceAgent.ServiceAgent.<>c_*DisplayClassa.b*_8(Object
>   s, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)    at
>   System.Net.WebClient.OnOpenReadCompleted(OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
>   at System.Net.WebClient.OpenReadOperationCompleted(Object arg)}
>       _className: "System.Net.WebException"
>       _data: null
>       _dynamicMethods: null
>       _exceptionMethod: null
>       _exceptionMethodString: null
>       _helpURL: null
>       _HResult: -2146233079
>       *innerException: {System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.    at
>   System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c*_DisplayClasse.b_*d(Object
>   sendState)    at
>   System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c*_DisplayClass1.b__0(Object
>   sendState)}
>       _ipForWatsonBuckets: 0
>       _message: "The remote server returned an error: NotFound."
>       _remoteStackIndex: 0
>       _remoteStackTraceString: null
>       _source: null
>       _stackTrace: {sbyte[96]}
>       _stackTraceString: null
>       _watsonBuckets: {byte[5616]}
>       _xcode: -532462766
>       *xptrs: 0
>       Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
>       HelpLink: null
>       HResult: -2146233079
>       InnerException: {System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.    at
>   System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c*_DisplayClasse.b_*d(Object
>   sendState)    at
>   System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c*_DisplayClass1.b__0(Object
>   sendState)}
>       IPForWatsonBuckets: 0
>       Message: "The remote server returned an error: NotFound."
>       RemoteStackTrace: null
>       Source: "System"
>       StackTrace: "   at System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary()\r\n
>   at System.Net.OpenReadCompletedEventArgs.get_Result()\r\n   at
>   xicihutong.DataServiceAgent.ServiceAgent.<>c_*DisplayClassa.b*_8(Object
>   s, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)\r\n   at
>   System.Net.WebClient.OnOpenReadCompleted(OpenReadCompletedEventArgs
>   e)\r\n   at System.Net.WebClient.OpenReadOperationCompleted(Object
>   arg)"
>       WatsonBuckets: {byte[5616]}

**Why? and how to handle it?**
unfortunately the error message I post is a Unhandle Exception and told me  that our server returns a error, but I thought that I've already catch the 404 error in the Unhandle exception, Why does it throw it anyway?

Comment: have you set `ID_CAP_NETWORKING` capability?

Answer (score 1):

To get more details about the reason of an exception, check the `Status` property of the `WebException` object. Also it can be a certificate problem if your app sends an *https* request.

Comment: unfortunately the error message I post is a Unhandle Exception and told me  that our server returns a error, but I thought that I've already catch the 404 error in the Unhandle exception, Why does it throw it anyway?

Answer (score 1):

You can't catch exception in described way because it is raised asynchronously in                  `OpenReadCompleted` event handler when you access `Result` property. In case an error has occurred you can't get a `Result` so an exception is raised. To handle it put `try catch` block inside the event handler, but actually to prevent an exception just don't pass a `Result` to callback in case an error has occurred.

Answer (score 0):

debug it and try opening the full address of the image you are downloading in the browser. Maybe there's a missing slash or something in the url.